# BadRequestError: request aborted . Node Js

Tags: node.js, cpanel, body-parser

I can't send 1 mb base64image json data with nodejs even though I have body-parser installed.

This is my app.js

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');

const authRoutes = require('./src/routes/auth');
const guestRoutes = require('./src/routes/guest');
const memberRoutes = require('./src/routes/member');

const isAuth = require('./src/middleware/jwtMiddleware');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
    credentials: true
}));

// Parse incoming request bodies in a middleware before your handlers, available under the req.body property
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));

// Serve static files from the 'public' directory
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/guest', guestRoutes);
app.use('/member', isAuth, memberRoutes);

app.use('/test', function (req, res) {
    return res.json(req.body);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

This is my error log

```
Node.js v20.9.0
BadRequestError: request aborted
    at IncomingMessage.onAborted (/home/iogmwebs/nodevenv/ykomara-backend.iogm.website/20/lib/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:245:10)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at IncomingMessage._destroy (node:_http_incoming:224:10)
    at _destroy (node:internal/streams/destroy:109:10)
    at IncomingMessage.destroy (node:internal/streams/destroy:71:5)
    at abortIncoming (node:_http_server:793:9)
    at socketOnClose (node:_http_server:787:3)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:337:12)
```

So this happens when in production cpanel nodejs. Previously I ran npm install and got the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'body-parser'
```

but I manually opened the cpanel terminal and installed it personally and it worked :

```
npm i body-parser

up to date, audited 242 packages in 2s

35 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm funds` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities.
```

I hope those of you who are experienced can answer this. Thank You